# Como faço para posicionar menu um ao lado do outro - CSS

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando criar um menu dropdown, que abre os sub-menu para baixo do botão, está funcionando corretamente até essa parte. Mas gostaria que os botões do Menu (DIV's) ficassem um ao lado do outro.  Porém está ficando uma em baixo da outra na lateral.

> ATUALIZADO

Encontrei meu erro, estava limitando a largura da coluna em 150px no `.dropdown` por isso jogava para baixo o outro botão, coloquei 100% e ficou lado a lado os botões.

Porém sempre que passo o mouse primeiro botão ele joga o segundo botão para baixo do submenu dele.  E quando passo o mouse no segundo botão, o submenu dele abre abaixo do primeiro botão.

Estou analisando o meu código mas não notei nada ainda. Se alguém perceber algo ocasionando isso.

Segue o código:

CSS:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu-superior {
    background-color: #242424 ;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 ;
}

.dropdown { /* Tamanho do wrapper do dropdown */
    width: 100%;
}

.dropdown a { /* Retira sublinhado das âncoras */
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-button { /* Estiliza o botão dropdown */
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: Green;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.dropdown-menu { /* Estiliza o menu dropdown */
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: none;
}

.menu-item { /* Estiliza cada item do dropdown */
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    color: White;
}

/* Mágica do dropdown */

/**
  * Seleciona o próximo elemento irmão do .dropdown-button, quando damos foco no dropdown.
  * Portanto, o irmão (menu de itens) é visualizado. */
.dropdown-button:hover + .dropdown-menu { 
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu:hover { /* Mantém o menu aberto, quando etiver com mouse sobre algum item*/
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-superior">
      <div class="dropdown">
         <a href="#0" class="dropdown-button">Minhas Contas</a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu">
                 <a href="#1" class="menu-item">Geral</a>
                 <a href="#2" class="menu-item">Vencidas</a>
                 <a href="#3" class="menu-item">Comprovantes</a>
         </div>
         <a href="#0" class="dropdown-button">Configurações</a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu">
                 <a href="#4" class="menu-item">Meus Dados</a>
                 <a href="#5" class="menu-item">Personalizar</a>
                 <a href="#6" class="menu-item">Sair</a>
         </div>
      </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está no seu css, você tem os elementos com posições fixas e ao lado um do outro. Elaborei aqui um meno de dropdown rapido para você perceber como funciona o dropdown(veja o exemplo em baixo). Dá uma olhadela em https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp Vai ajudar a perceber como fazer um dropdown sem acontecer o movimento dos botões.

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Minhas Contas</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">geral</a>
    <a href="#">vencidos</a>
    <a href="#">comprovantes</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Configurações</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">meus dados</a>
    <a href="#">personalizar</a>
    <a href="#">sair</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado maninho, me ajudou muito.   Eu havia pesquisado sobre e montei esse código, mas vou dar uma olhada nesse artigo do w3 para entender melhor como funciona. Abraço.